# Get specific tag value for a scenario in JBehave

Tags: jbehave

If there any way to get value for @dataset tag for the following scenario in JBehave?

```
Scenario: Open/close chat and send messages
    @dataset set2
    Given user is logged into the system
    When user opens chat
    ...
```

I've tried

```
@BeforeScenario
public void getdata(@Named("dataset") String dataset) {
    System.out.println(dataset);
```

But that doesn't work if @dataset is defined for a particular scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite easy

```
Scenario: Open/close chat and send messages
    META: @dataset set2
    Given user is logged into the system
    When user opens chat
```

You should add "META:" before the tag name

Comment: This saved my day, thanks. I used that in @AfterScenario and it works fine too. 
`@AfterScenario(uponOutcome = AfterScenario.Outcome.FAILURE)
public void afterFailedScenario(@Named("TestId") String testId){
   LOGGER.info(testId);
}`